# Is it possible to write python code in spec file which is generated by pyinstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller

There are some commands that has to be executed with spec file. Is there any possibility to include commands in spec file.

I have to execute the following statement:

```
rm -rf build dist
```

I need to include in spec file.

When I run

```
pyinstaller --clean abc.spec
```

it has to delete build folder and dist folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pyinstaller documentation:

> The spec file tells PyInstaller how to process your script. It encodes the script names and most of the options you give to the pyinstaller command. **The spec file is actually executable Python code.** PyInstaller builds the app by executing the contents of the spec file.

So, you can include python code in the spec file to perform the operations you want.  But it will need to be python code, not terminal commands as you have.

Comment: Having said this, it looks like you are trying to remove the two folders that are created by pyinstaller.  Since all of pyinstaller's output is located in the these two directories that you are trying to delete immediately after they are created, I don't see the point in running pyinstaller at all.